# Compiling standalone selenium: Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from

Tags: java, selenium

I'm a total Java noob so please understand =) I need a quick advice on how to fix the issue.

I cloned the official selenium git repo, changed the code a bit (need to dump the page into some specified dirs), and tried to rebuilt it:

```
./go //java/server/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/server:server:uber //java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium:client-combined:uber
```

It was successful but when I tried to execute it I got this:

```
$ java -jar build/java/server/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/server/server-standalone.jar 
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
build/java/server/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/server/server-standalone.jar
```

Tried to check classpath, CLASS_PATH and CLASSPATH env variables (as a friend of mine suggested) - I simply don't have any.

At the same time, the pre-compiled standalone server from the official downloads works out of the box.

The official docs didn't help. There's nothing about it there.

So - I need a quick advice how to compile it? Thanks.

P.S. JDK 8 (latest), Mac OS 10.7

P.P.S. That friend of mine tried to build it by himself and he was lucky - he got a new build/dist folder where the target big file was. But in my case, the build folder is created, but there's not 'dist' folder in it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer: I should have built it like that:

```
./go clean release
```

it's really strange that all the docs state I need to use these long /bla/bla/:uber things to get a whole single 'uber' server.